# How to convert E00 to ESRI format?

Tags: e00

Is there a programmatic (or otherwise portable) way to convert E00 ArcInfo interchange files into ESRI format?

Comment: see arcpy code at the bottom of http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001300000028000000

Comment: Several other questions about e00 files have answers or comments that state that ogr2ogr can convert .e00 files.

Answer (score 3):

See this article: [Importing an ArcInfo interchange file (E00)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00140000001s000000)

There is also a script in ArcToolbox called **Import from E00 (conversion)**

> Imports an ArcInfo Workstation interchange file (.e00). An interchange
>   file is used to transport coverages, INFO tables, text files such as
>   AML macros, and other ArcInfo files. For coverages, grids, and tins,
>   it contains all information, including appropriate INFO table
>   information. Interchange files are designated with the .e00 file
>   suffix. This is the ArcView GIS version of the utility for importing
>   .e00 files.

Answer (score 2):

So you didn't define "Esri format".  As pointed out, in the Esri silo there are tools that help perform this conversion.  You can also use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to perform this conversion.  The details of the e00 format are [here](http://www.gdal.org/drv_avce00.html).  Something like:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.e00
```